# std::string search for numbers in a string & insert space before & after

Tags: c++, string

I have this string:

> string strInput = "33kfkdsfhk33  324234k334k     333 3   323434/545435436***33/rrrr34       e3mdgmflkgfdlglk3434424dfffff555555555555gggggg00000033lll-111111 1974-1-12";

I would like to format it as:

> " 33 kfkdsfhk 33    324234 k 334 k      333   3     323434 / 545435436 *** 33 /rrrr 34        e 3 mdgmflkgfdlglk 3434424 dfffff 555555555555 gggggg 00000033lll - 111111   1974 - 1 - 12 ";

That is, find a number and insert space before and after the number.

No Boost please... only standard C++ library.

This is what I tried, inserts space after number, i want to group all consecutive numbers to get desired output.

```
strInput = "33kfkdsfhk33  324234k334k     333 3   323434/545435436***33/rrrr34       e3mdgmflkgfdlglk3434424dfffff555555555555gggggg00000033lll-111111 1974-1-12";
for ( std::string::iterator it=strInput.begin(); it!=strInput.end(); ++it)
{
    static bool flag = false;
    if(isdigit(*it) && !flag)
    {
        strInput.insert(it,1,' ');
        flag = true;
    }
    else
        flag = false;
}
```

Comment: I revised the original question with code snippet.

Comment: I barely know C++, but that use of `insert` rises a red flag for me. Isn't it (at least potentially) invalidating your iterators and isn't that a very very bad thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution actually looks fairly good conceptually, but there is one major problem: After you `insert` into a string, all iterators pointing to it may be invalid, in particular your loop iterator `it`. That can lead to segfaults and all kinds of hard-to-explain bugs.

As an alternative solution, I would suggest not modifying the string you start with, but just reading from it and building a new one step by step, inserting spaces where you want them as you go along. This is really only a minor modification of your current code!

```
string strInput = ... // whatever;
string newString = "";
bool currentisdigit = false;
bool previouswasdigit = false;
for ( std::string::iterator it=strInput.begin(); it!=strInput.end(); ++it)
{
    previouswasdigit = currentisdigit;
    currentisdigit = isdigit(*it);
    if(currentisdigit && !previouswasdigit)
        newString.push_back(' ');
    if(!currentisdigit && previouswasdigit)
        newString.push_back(' ');
    newString.push_back(*it);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you? Create a new `string` as well, and write to that instead of the old one. This requires only minor modifications to your current code.

Comment: @user2079702 You don't need `copy`, `transform` or anything like that, just a really minor modification of your current program. I have included a sample in my answer above.

Comment: +1, but additional check if there is no space adjacent to a digit already wouldn't hurt. Also it could be a good idea to reserve some space in the new string from the start.

Comment: @Maciej Agreed, but this question is really likely to be homework. Given that fact, I feel that the answer I have provided is a little too detailed already.